# Dynamics CRM Email management

Tags: email, dynamics-crm

I want to learn different ways how you guys handle incoming emails in Dynamics CRM.

1. How you make sure that everyone is responding to their emails?
2. Can we filter incoming emails to get the ones which are not yet
   replied? On daily basis we are getting a lot of emails and we want
   to have a filtered view where we can only see the emails which are
   not yet replied yet.
3. How you deal with incoming emails which are sent to sales@
   accounting@ etc.

   3A. How you distribute them among different users?

   - Assigning to them?
   - Forwarding to them?

   3B. And how you make sure that they are replying to those emails?

I will appreciate if you I can learn from your experience on this subject

Comment: I don't see how this a programming question.

Comment: @Robert The reason could be that you are not aware of the Dynamics CRM platform! Dynamics CRM email management can be automated using custom C# code to build workflows and plugins.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Maybe you should include some code in your question then? Looks to me like it's about configuration only? Again, as you said, I don't know Dynamics CRM.

Comment: @Robert, there are a large number of Dynamics questions on Stack already, ~6000 for `dynamics-crm`. Dynamics can be customised and extended with and without code. Not every question has to have code; these types of questions tend to fall within ["a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

Use the existing Customer Service module which Microsoft has built for this purpose. Incoming emails create Case records, which are actionable items with associated statuses.

**How you make sure that everyone is responding to their emails?**

Set up workflows so that unassigned cases cause escalation of some sort (i.e. an email sent to a manager)

**Can we filter incoming emails to get the ones which are not yet replied? On daily basis we are getting a lot of emails and we want to have a filtered view where we can only see the emails which are not yet replied yet.**

Filter by Case status

**How you deal with incoming emails which are sent to sales@ accounting@ etc.
 - How you distribute them among different users?**

You can set up routing logic so that cases are tagged with specific attributes, or assigned to specific users based on what address the originating email targeted.

**Assigning to them?**

This is out of the box case functionality

**Forwarding to them?**

Set up a workflow to send an email to the case owner or other user

**And how you make sure that they are replying to those emails?**

A simple option is to review the email history associated with the case. Automating this task is certainly possible but can get complicated.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could add each email into a queue, and have users process emails out of the queue.

There is a setting to enable this on the entity configuration with the customisations area.

[image]

Emails when tracked or synchronised then appear within Dynamics within the queue.

[image]

Users then process the queue. This also caters for the scenario where emails do not need a reply - they can be removed from the queue. In this model, the emphasis switches from checking emails are replied to, to checking queues are cleared.

2. Reply email are linked back to the original email via the Parent Activity Id. So you could build a filter around this.

[image]

3. [Create a queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customer-service/set-up-queues-manage-activities-cases) for these to receive email.

> The email address that you enter in the Incoming Email field receives all messages sent to the queue.

- A) Users can pick items from the queue, a team leader can assign queue items to others, or use bespoke customisation or development to automatically route items.
- B) As above.